# Google Places API returning only 5 results and I use predictions google place JSON

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-places-api

I use this code for auto complete 
but it show me just 5 result

```
data = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");


                for (int i = 1; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));

                    AutoData nn = new AutoData(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("terms").getJSONObject(i).getString("value"),
                            predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                    data.add(nn);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
            }

            adapter = new DataAdapter(data,MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            if (!data.isEmpty()) {

                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
```

and json is:

> predictions google place json

how can I fix this problem???

Comment: Explain  your problem. Normally Place Autocomplete will only give 5 results.If you need more results then use Google places api instead.

Comment: I want to show more results

Comment: Then use Google Places api.

Comment: I use  Google Places api but show me 5 results

Comment: I can see that this feature was requested in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821928, but Google marked it as Infeasible. So there is no way to get more than 5 items in place autocomplete.